# How do I get my second media query to work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Why can't second media query change the width property to 100% when the display changes below 600px?

I want when opened on a screen below 600px the width property will be 100%.

I tried it in w3s editor and it worked. and if I try on Google Chrome it doesn't work. I opened it and looked through the Chrome web console, the results were not as expected. when the screen is below 600px the width remains at 50% even though I want the width to be 100% according to my second media query. Is this a problem with Chrome or something?

Take a look at my latest screenshot

[image: Web console]

[image: W3C editor]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: serif;
}

body {
  background: url(latihan/aset/gambar/a.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  background: white;
}

#chk1 {
  display: none;
}

i {
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .logo {
  flex: 1;
  color: #251e1e;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header ul {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

header ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
}

header ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(201, 63, 63);
}

header .menu {
  display: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  header ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    width: 50%;
    left: -100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    transition: left 0.5s linear;
  }
  header ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  header .menu {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #chk1:checked~ul {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  header ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Web Master</h1>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu">
      <label for="chk1"><i>Ikon</i></label>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Works perfectly in my testing: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-banach-xhtm7q?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The media query seems to work fine, but you still have the list off screen with the large negative margin. Please revise to be more specific about the problem.

Comment: When I run your snippet and use the **full page** link, which you need to do for any testing of responsive behaviour, it seems to work fine. I don't see any problem.

Comment: I tried it in w3c editor and it worked. and if I try on Google Chrome it doesn't work. I opened it and looked through the Chrome web console, the results were not as expected. when the screen is below 300px the width remains at 50% even though I want the width to be 100% according to my second media query. Is this a problem with Chrome or something?

Comment: Take a look at my latest screenshot

Comment: The W3C don’t provide an editor.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant W3S

Comment: You seem to be using mobile device emulation instead of just resizing your browser window. Does it work if you resize the browser window instead?

Comment: as I screenshot, if I use a code editor like W3S or codesandbox it works. but if I try the results via a browser (locally without internet), it doesn't look as expected, so I want to know whether this problem is in the browser or what?. Or is the problem only with the web console? I want to know